Does Transcoder API support segmenting MV-HEVC files?
According to Apple (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10071/), the HLS multivariant playlist format for their spatial videos (MV-HEVC files) should be:

EXT-X-VERSION is updated to version 12
New REQ-VIDEO-LAYOUT attribute

For EXT-X-STREAM-INF tag for video content
Video Channel Specifier can have values CH-STEREO or CH-MONO or a mix



Does the transcoder API support it?

It seems that Google Transcoder API does not officially support segmenting MV-HEVC (Multiview HEVC) files.
Here's a couple of resources that mention this limitation.

GCP transcoder API is very slow with HEVC (h.265) videos

Overview of the Transcoder API


